# Implement cryptography algorithms in an ARM microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, c, arm, c++, iar

Assume a situation in which you want do some encryption procedures in your ARM microcontroller. (Receive a file, encrypt with 3DES and some hash functions and returning it, for example.)

As far as I know we have two option here:

1. Reinventing the wheel! i.e. writing some functions to do described cryptography algorithms.
2. Adding already-written libraries in our project and using their methods simply.

Now I want to benefit from the second solution using *[OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL)* libraries. But I'm not sure about it! Is it possible to add these libraries to the **IAR** IDE? Shall I recompile the *OpenSSL* source code before adding to my program?

I really appreciate a step-by-step solution.

Comment: "Encrypt with ... and some hashes" -- multiple hashes does **not** provide security and may in fact introduce weaknesses. If you only plan to do different hashes on different inputs there's no problem though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you will need to recompile the library in IAR to be able to use it in your project. You can find step-by-step instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283727/iar-embedded-workbench-create-library).

I suggest to take a look at [mbedTLS](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls) or [Tiny SSL](https://tls.mbed.org/tiny-ssl-library) instead of OpenSSL, as your project will probably benefit from using a smaller library.

Comment: Agreed - OpenSSL is a huge legacy package which is hard to work with. Consider also http://nacl.cr.yp.to/ . If you *just* want 3DES (obsolete!) and SHA-2, you can get those seperately as reference implementations. Don't forget to use the correct CBC mode, IV, key scheduling and padding modes!

Comment: @pjc50 Can I use _NACL_ in my ARM programs also?

Comment: As I want to do some Signature generation and verification I think the _OpenSSL_ is the only option, right?

Comment: I believe you need SHA-2 for this. It is implemented in mbedTLS as well.

Comment: NaCl is targetted at ARM: http://www.hyperelliptic.org/tanja/vortraege/20121129.pdf and can do signatures, although only crypto_sign_edwards25519sha512batch and not PGP-compatible signatures.